# converting from signed int to unsigned int without casting

Tags: c

```
int isNegative(int x) {
  return ((unsigned) x)>> 31;
}
```

I'm writing a function that takes 32 bits and returns 1 if x<0, and 0 otherwise. How do I convert a signed int to an unsigned int without casting.

Comment: Unclear why code is not simply `return x < 0` as that meets the higher level goal of "returns 1 if x<0, and 0 otherwise.".  Of course that does not answer the lower goals - which I find a bit unclear.

Comment: If you want your function to take a 32 bit datatype, that is a "long" not int.

Comment: Why do you need to convert without casting?  That's what casting is *for*.

Comment: @chux: That would avoid the UB for any `int` width != 32

Comment: You function does not take 32 bits, but anything between 16 and `INF` bits, depending on your platform. If you want 32 bits, use fixed width types.

Comment: @Fredrik: A `long` is not guaranteed to have 32 bits either!

Comment: How do you want to convert the integer `-3` to `unsigned int` ???  Why didn't you write your function like `int isNegative(int x) { return x < 0; }` ???

Answer (score 4):

OP has different implied questions

> a function that takes 32 bits and returns 1 if x<0, and 0 otherwise.

```
int isNegative(int x) {
  return x < 0;
}
// or maybe return bool/_Bool
bool isNegative(int x) {
  return x < 0;
}
// or pedantically
int isNegative(int_least32_t x) {
  return x < 0;
}
// or pedantically and nearly universally portable,
int isNegative(int32_t x) {
  return x < 0;
}
```

> converting from signed int to unsigned int without casting (and)
>   How do I convert a `signed int` to an `unsigned int` without casting.

Simply assign the value

```
 int i;
 unsigned u = i;
```

---

Attempting to use `>>` to combined these two risk implementation defined behavior and should be avoided unless compelling reasons are given.

> EXAMPLE An example of implementation-defined behavior is the propagation of the high-order bit when a signed integer is shifted right. C11§3.4.2 2

Answer (score 1):

Your question is to write a function that takes 32 bits and returns `1` if `x < 0`

```
int isNegative(int x) {
    return x < 0;
}
```

This will work no matter what the size of `int` and does not invoke any type conversions. I suppose you have over-thought this problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is a variety of operations that perform automatic type conversions, among them assignments, arithmetic operations under certain conditions, and function calls (conversion of certain argument values).

Thus, you could achieve conversion of (`signed`) `int` arguments to `unsigned int` simply by declaring that to be the parameter type:

```
int isNegative(unsigned x) {
  return x >> 31;
}
```

Admittedly, however, that function interface could be a little confusing.  You might therefore prefer to do this:

```
int isNegative(int x) {
  unsigned ux = x;
  return x >> 31;
}
```

However, I don't think either of those is as clear as your original version, with its cast.  Type conversion is the entire purpose of a cast, and when conversion is what you need (and all that you need), a cast is the right tool for the job.

Of course, I do overall prefer the even simpler family of approaches suggested by @chux.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you don't need to.  If you get rid of the cast, right shifting retains the sign bit.

Assuming `int` is 32 bit, removing the cast results in -1 for negative numbers and 0 for nonnegative numbers.  While the actual return value differs for the nonnegative case, in a Boolean context it will work as you expect.

Comment: Detail: "results in -1 for negative numbers and 0 for nonnegative" is _very_ common yet implementation-defined behavior.

Comment: Answer is restrictive, but DV is excessive.

Answer (score 0):

To have an unsigned version of an integer without casting, or creating a new number, multiply by -1 if negative (if a == INT_MAX, it is positive, and no multiplication will occur) :

```
#include <iostream>

int main (int argc, char* argv []) {
    int a (-132);
    std::cout << "a == " << a << std::endl;
    if (a < 0) a *= -1;
    std::cout << "unsigned a  == " << a << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: The question is tagged [c], not [c++].  Furthermore your code would have undefined behavior for `a == INT_MAX`.